# Draw shapes rounding a circle with UIBezierPath in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, draw, uibezierpath

Digging in drawing shapes like the following, and each shape can be touched and moved. So I think SpriteKit combined with UIBezierPath can do it.

[image]

Here is my codes:

```
for i in 1...20{
            let shape = SKShapeNode()
            shape.path = createPointerPath().cgPath
            shape.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX-10, y: frame.midY+40)
            shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.439, blue: 0.678, alpha: 1.0)
            shape.strokeColor = .white
            shape.lineWidth = 2
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            let r = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(i)*15.0, duration: 0.1)
            shape.run(r)
            addChild(shape)
            shapeArr.append(shape)
        }
```

Create shap:

```
func createPointerPath() -> UIBezierPath {
    let pointerHeight:CGFloat = 80
    let pointerWidth: CGFloat = 20
    let pointerPath = UIBezierPath()
    pointerPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:pointerWidth / 2, y:0))
    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:pointerWidth / 2, y:pointerHeight),
                         controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:pointerWidth / 2, y:0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:-pointerWidth, y:pointerHeight))
    pointerPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x:pointerWidth / 2, y:0),
                         controlPoint1: CGPoint(x:pointerWidth * 2, y:pointerHeight), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:pointerWidth / 2, y:0))
    return pointerPath
}
```

and I got the following:

[image]

The shapes just rotate to make a circle. and there are two problems here:

1. The strokes look ugly, each shape only has half stroke.
2. What I really want is:

   -- Get the shapes number first.

   -- Calculate the width of each shape from the fixed margin so that each shape displays averagely.

   -- Create the shape from the center, but not rotate.

can anyone give more suggestion?

Thx.

Comment: You should always show some effort in solving the issue... I mean, you can get lucky and have your answers, but questions like this are against SO rules.

Comment: @Whirlwind sorry. I post my code now.